# Prior Art Request - Self Serve Wine Glasses

Tags: us20030019364, us20070294983, us20100092623

**Method for packing wine or a similar beverage, products obtained using said method and device for carrying out the method**

**US 20030019364 A1**

**Abstract**

> The present invention relates to a method of packaging wine or a
>   similar beverage, to products obtained by the method, and to apparatus
>   for implementing the method. The present invention provides a method
>   of packaging wine or a similar beverage in a receptacle in the form of
>   a drinking glass (9), in which method said receptacle is made of glass
>   and said glass receptacle is closed by means of a disposable capsule
>   (1) having very low overall permeability to oxygen after being closed
>   onto said receptacle

The patent application appears to be a continuation of a foriegn patent. This patent application was the foundation for "Patended Technology" as seen on Shark Tank with Copa Di Vino wines. Mr James Martin claims he was the patentee of the enhanced single serve bottled wine glasses and he never once said "Patent Pending" during the 3 episodes he appeared on, he eluded to having "Patented Technology".

I have no vested interest in this, yet I find the methods to be similar to individual packaging of apple sauce, baby foods, yogurts, puddings, and other self serve containers that have been in existence for quite some time.

Please share any prior art you may have. I feel this patent was improperly represented in front of millions of viewers and investors as "Patented" when in fact it appears to be "Patent Pending" with no guarantee of a grant based on the rejection of the claims.

Comment: Im not sure why the title is calling from prior-art -- it looks to me that your actual question is about whether he has a patent or not, and if he should have represented hims self as having a "patent pending" -- is that not the real question?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the German version of the patent has been granted

http://www.google.com/patents/DE60011927T2

So on that basis, im sure he can claim that he has a patent -- as long as he does not claim he has a US patent.